# How to display a div next to another div with no width defined?

Tags: html, css, width

I'm working on an horizontal scrolling website. I have a cover background, then a black div with text in columns, and finally, I would like to have a green div to the right of the previous div.

The structure of my page is as follows :

```
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="post-content">
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <div id="text"><!-- columns --></div>
    <div id="theend"><p>THE END</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS is as follows :

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; background:black; }
#content { position:absolute; height:100%; top:0; left:0; }
#post-content { position:relative; background:transparent; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; }
#cover { left:0; top:0; position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; background: url('http://www.inveralmondchs.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/waterfall-godafoss-iceland.jpg') center no-repeat fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; background-attachment: scroll; }
#text { float:left; width: auto; height:100%; left:100%; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-size:15px; text-align: left; color:white; font-family:'open sans'; -webkit-column-width: 300px; -webkit-column-gap: 40px; -moz-column-width: 300px; -moz-column-gap: 40px; -moz-column-count: auto; column-width: 300px; column-gap: 40px; }
#theend { float:left; height:100%; position: relative; width:300px; text-align:center; background: green; color:white; }
```

You can see the demo in this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/47/

I think that the problem is about the `width` of `#text`. Because I can't define it precisely since my website is dynamic. Then, the green div `#theend` appears at the bottom left instead of appearing to the right of the black div with columns.

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the third div's position absolute:

```
#theend { float:left; height:100%; position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; width:300px; text-align:center; background: green; color:white; }
```

And then set the position through Javascript:

```
var w1 = document.getElementById("cover").scrollWidth + document.getElementById("text").scrollWidth; document.getElementById("theend").style.left = w1 + "px";
```

I forked your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxb0p8ro/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
#cover, #text, #theend {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

then test the arrangement by putting some displayable text inside all three inner-most divs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/48/ it still doesn't work...

Comment: Try a real browser. Another way out is to replace the 3 inner divs with spans and set the display of the spans to block, but then that would defeat your DIV arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

- first off - position cover above content as they are both absolute.
- Change #theend to float right
- finally try to change/remove  -moz-column-width: 300px; and webkit-column . I removed it and it looks good.

This helps to get the green div on the right and the background static but I still dont see the text displayed. Will let you know if I find how to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure to have understood your suggestion. Here is the new demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/49/ (the cover has disappeared, there's no column anymore etc...)

Comment: Can you try it on a browser than jsfiddle. They work differently. I updated the div positioning in the demo.

Comment: Are you talking about this version you updated ? jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/49/ Anyway, I put in a real HTML page : http://arkhana.fr/metalchest/testsanscms/test/test.html. But I don't have the cover and the columns anymore (and the green div is at the bottom).